# How I know which button been clicked in class of buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have the class of buttons and I want to know which one been clicked using JavaScript

```html
    <button class="editors">Edit</button>
    <button class="editors">Edit</button>
    <button class="editors">Edit</button>
```

so I want to know which button is clicked

Comment: You can get your buttons with document.querySelectorAll(".editors") and store them as a array and use foreach and add items click event then you can see your button which you clicked with event.target

Comment: what is the use case of doing so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach event listener to the document or your button's wrapper element/div and then use the **`event.target`** property. That way you use only 1 event listener, instead of attaching multiple for each element. This approach is called **[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)**. You can check the different **`event`** properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties).

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  let element = evt.target;
  console.log(`Clicked button: ${element.textContent}`);
});
```

```html
<button class="editors">Edit</button>
<button class="editors">Details</button>
<button class="editors">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass *this* to your function and then you have a reference to the clicked button.

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('editors')].forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myFunction(this);
  })
});


function myFunction(el) {
  console.log(el);
}
```

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('editors')].forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myFunction(this);
  })
});


function myFunction(el) {
  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<button class="editors">1</button>
<button class="editors">2</button>
<button class="editors">3</button>
```